# .PKPASS as inline content

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, passbook, magnolia

Please can some one help me out with my problem. I would like to send a passkit (`.PKPASS`) as attachment via Java mail. If I place this attachment as inline content, the passbook is not displayed as inline content in the massage body in the mail client on apple devices. On windows devices everything works properly.

```
MailAttachment mailAttachment = new MailAttachment;
mailAttachment = new MailAttachment(passbookTemp, "passbook","passbook","inline");
```

Comment: You need to set the mime type corrcectly to `application/vnd.apple.pkpass`

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer. Where should I put the mimetype? In the mail template or in java application?

Comment: Where can I find documentation to the MailAttachment function you are using? Most likely, one of the fields you are passing the string "passbook" too is the MIME type.

Comment: Hi, i am use the magnolia cms source code,  https://git.magnolia-cms.com/projects/MODULES/repos/mail/browse/src/main/java/info/magnolia/module/mail/templates/MailAttachment.java?at=MGNLMAIL-71

Comment: See here https://git.magnolia-cms.com/projects/MODULES/repos/mail/browse/src/main/java/info/magnolia/module/mail/templates/MailAttachment.java?at=MGNLMAIL-71#178 my guess is that .pkpass is not a registered MIME type and is being set incorrectly.  You may need to trace that call and manually add the correct type.